# Trying to output content from page, works locally but not online

Tags: wp-query

I am using the following code, to output the content from a page with the id of two. This is in my custom template file which is selected in the page. It works fine locally but online it does not work, it outputs nothing, the id is based of this url `http://www.goodmorningmoon.ca/wp-admin/post.php?post=2&action=edit`
What might I do to diagnose this problem.

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('page_id=2'); ?>
<?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Did you replicate the database for each instance with dump or manually?

Comment: I didn't replicate the database, I just added the same content to the page.

Comment: So you've got two different versions of your site, one locally and one online, and each uses a different database. When you make edits locally you then try to manually recreate your work online? 

I ask because if you go about developing WP this way it's really easy to forget to update certain settings or create inconsistencies. For example, if you make 5 new pages locally in a certain order, you must do it in the exact same order online or else their page ID's will be inconsistent.

Your code looks correct, but I suspect it has something to do with a discrepancy in the databases.

Comment: Are you sure the page id is the same and that you have published it?

Comment: I will try and sync the databases from now on. There is no way to sync all of the settings I have locally to the online version such as permalinks structure or menu order or plugin settings is there. Can I only keep the databases in sync.

Comment: why not use get_page()? instead

Comment: @AndersKitson - it's all in the database- permalink settings, plugin settings, menus, as well as all of your content.

Comment: @helgatheviking, I am going to try get_page()? I am going to read the codex first, could you place this as a answer so I can choose it if it works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried get_page() ?

```
$page_id = 123; // 123 should be replaced with a specific Page's id from your site,

$page = get_page( $page_id ); // You must pass in a variable to the get_page function. 

echo '<h3>'. $page->post_title .'</h3>';// echo the page title

echo apply_filters('the_content', $page->post_content); // Get Content and retain Wordpress filters such as paragraph tags.
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page

don't forget to make sure you change the $page_id to match your live version